# Como abrir um link com o texto de uma div

Tags: javascript

Quero criar um botão e o *link* que abrir nele seja de uma `div` que esteja no meu site por exemplo em JavaCcript

```
var elemento = document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML;

button2.onclick = function() {
 window.open(elemento)
}
```

o `var elemento` recebe a URL e quando clico no botão abre a url do elemento `('teste').innerHTML`;

Como faço isso? Esse não funciona.

Comment: Não funciona? O que acontece? Como definiu `button2`? E qual é o valor na `div`? Aliás, qual é a estrutura do HTML?

Comment: estou perguntando como faço isso só dei um exemplo bobo

Comment: o link que o botão for abrir quando clicar nele ser de um elemento que coloquei na pagina,por exemplo crio uma div com uma url e quero que o link do botão seja a texto da mesma.

Comment: Pelo o que descreveu, seu exemplo chega bem próximo de fazer o que quer. Tente implementar baseado no seu exemplo e, se não funcionar, edite sua pergunta com algo mais concreto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o texto do elemento e colocar no primeiro parâmetro do `window.open` que se refere à URL que será aberta na janela:

**HTML**

```
<div id="teste">
    http://url_foo.com
</div>

<button>Abrir</button>
```

**JS**

```
button2 = document.querySelector("button");
button2.onclick = function() {
   var elemento = document.querySelector("#teste").innerText.trim();
   var popup = window.open(elemento,'_blank','width=500, height=300');
}
```

**[Teste no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cqo4tnp/1/)**

Comment: quase isso amigo,quero que o link que seja aberta ao invés de conter o texto a url dele seja o texto

Comment: <div id="teste">
   www.google.com
   <br />
   <strong>Olá!</strong>
</div>

<button>Abrir</button>

Comment: @MinelopsMl Resposta atualizada. Veja se era isso?

Comment: funcionou sim,muito obrigado!  ;)